# Filter DataFrame Values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following DataFrame:

| Student | food |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | R0100000 |
| 2 | R0200000 |
| 3 | R0300000 |
| 4 | R0400000 |

I need to test if the Student = 1, a new "Selected_Food" string should be created with "R0100000" value. If the Student = 3, then the "Selected_Food" string should be contain the "R0300000" value and so on.

This is the code to create the same DataFrame as mine:

```
    data={'Student':[1,2,3,4],'food':['R0100000', 'R0200000', 'R0300000', 'R0400000']}
    df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The following code works for the first case , but it doesnt work if I change the Student value.

```
if(df.Student==1):
Selected_food=df.loc[0,"food"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check like below: ([`pandas.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html))

```
def func_chck(df, stu_num, food_slct):
    return (df.loc[df['Student'].eq(stu_num), 'food'] == food_slct).values[0]

>>> func_chck(df, 1, 'R0400000')
False

>>> func_chck(df, 1, 'R0100000')
True
```